# What is the meaning of operator ||=

Tags: perl, operators

In Perl, what's the meaning of operator `||=` in the following example ?

```
$sheet -> {MaxCol} ||= $sheet -> {MinCol};
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html

Answer (score 7):

`a ||= b` is similar to `a = a || b`, so:

```
$sheet->{MaxCol} ||= $sheet->{MinCol};
```

is similar to:

```
$sheet->{MaxCol} = $sheet->{MaxCol} || $sheet->{MinCol};
```

Per ikegami's comment, the difference is that `a ||= b;` only evaluates `a` once, and it evaluates `a` before `b`. This matters when `a` is magical or isn't a scalar.

Answer (score 5):

```
$sheet -> {MaxCol} ||= $sheet -> {MinCol};
```

have same effect as

```
if (!$sheet->{MaxCol}) { $sheet->{MaxCol} = $sheet->{MinCol}; }
```

or

```
$sheet->{MaxCol} = $sheet->{MinCol} unless $sheet->{MaxCol};
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers said: it's one of the shorthands Perl offers.

`$a += $b` is *almost* identical to `$a = $a + $b`.

Why almost? Well, the number of accesses to $a might cause different side effects. For example if $a is actually a tied variable.  Tie-ing a variable/hash/array/filehandle gives you hooks into reading from and writing to storage (be it RAM that Perl took or a database file somewhere or simple access to sensors (temperature, humidity, ... )

See perldoc -f tie for more information.

You probably can already imagine that this can be very powerful, not unlike Unix' "everything is a file" access to all kinds of devices through a pretty unified and universal interface ...

There are other shorthands in Perl:

- `$a **= $b` (as in $a is $a to the power of $b),
- `+=`, `-=`, `*/`, `/=` --- pretty much as it says on the tin,
- `%=` modulo
- `$a x= $b`, repeating the string in $a tor $b times
- `&=, |=, ^=`, bitwise and, or, XOR
- `&.=`, `|.=`, `^.=`, same `&=` etc. but operands are *forced* to be interpreted as strings
- `<<=`, `>>=` are for bitwise shifting
- `$a &&= $b` is "if $a evaluates as true, set it to $b".
- `||=` is "if $a evaluates as false (empty string, value zero or undefined), set $a to $b.  A great way to set default values if 0 or empty string cannot be valid input.
- `\\=`, my favourite, is nearly the same as `||=` except it will not set $a to $b even if $a is 0 or an empty string.